# Select data according to previous selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI steeper what my task is in step one I have 2 check box and in step 2 also I have two check box so I need to set the condition depending on selection mean if I select Individual in step one and instep to if I select First Screening then in step 3 my one component show, for example, textField show if I select bulk in step 1 and the first screen in step 2 then my other component show, for example, file upload field son I need to set depends on selection or true condition in next mean in step 3 data will show in anyone step means in step 1 not able to check both check box at a time only one check box will select in a single step you can also see CodeSandBox link

```
import React from "react";
import {
  makeStyles,
  Stepper,
  Step,
  StepLabel,
  Button,
  TextField,
  Typography,
  Grid,
  Box,
  Card,
  Checkbox,
  CardContent
} from "@material-ui/core";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  instructions: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  backButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
  }
}));

function getSteps() {
  return [
    "first",
    "second",
    "theird",
    "forth",
    "fivth"
  ];
}

function getStepContent(stepIndex) {
  switch (stepIndex) {
    case 0:
      return (
        <Box>
          <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
            <Checkbox
              color="primary"
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
            />
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" noWrap={true}>
              Individual
            </Typography>
          </Box>
          <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
            <Checkbox
              defaultChecked
              color="primary"
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
            />
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" noWrap={true}>
              Bulk
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      );
    case 1:
      return (
        <Box>
          <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
            <Checkbox
              defaultChecked
              color="primary"
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
            />
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" noWrap={true}>
              first Screening
            </Typography>
          </Box>
          <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
            <Checkbox
              color="primary"
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
            />
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" noWrap={true}>
              second Screening
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      );
    case 2:
      return [
        "Individual first Screening ",
        "Individual second Screening ",
        "Bulk first Screening ",
        "Bulk second Screening "
      ];
    case 3:
      return (
        <TextField
          id="outlined-select-currency"
          label="Target Date"
          variant="outlined"
          size="small"
          type="date"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true
          }}
          name="target_Date"
        ></TextField>
      );
    case 4:
      return (
        <Grid>
          <Box
            display="flex"
            justifyContent="center"
            alignItems="center"
            mt={3}
          >
            <Box mr={2}>
              title="Alert" icon="icon"
              <Checkbox
                name="alert"
                // checked={rules.exactNameMatch}
                color="primary"
                inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
                // onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
              />
            </Box>
            <Box m={2} ml={2}>
              title="Non Alerts" icon="icon"
              <Checkbox
                name="nonAlert"
                // checked={rules.exactNameMatch}
                color="primary"
                inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
                // onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
              />
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      );
    default:
      return "Unknown stepIndex";
  }
}

const Initiate = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const steps = getSteps();

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };
  const handleStep = (step) => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => {
      return step < prevActiveStep ? step : prevActiveStep;
    });
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };

  return (
    <Grid container direction="column" justify="center">
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel>
        {steps.map((label, index) => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel onClick={() => handleStep(index)}>{label}</StepLabel>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
      <Box mt={3}></Box>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
        {activeStep === steps.length ? (
          <Box>
            <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
              All steps completed
            </Typography>
            <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
          </Box>
        ) : (
          <Box>
            <Card>
              <CardContent>
                <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
                  {getStepContent(activeStep)}
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
            <Box
              mt={2}
              display="flex"
              alignItems="center"
              justifyContent="flex-end"
            >
              <Button
                disabled={activeStep === 0}
                onClick={handleBack}
                className={classes.backButton}
              >
                Back
              </Button>
              <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleNext}>
                {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        )}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
export default Initiate;
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-skred?file=/demo.js:0-5572)

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep track of the selections in step one and two. You can do this in many ways.

The one way I can think of is using `state`.

For this, you will have to move the function `getStepContent` inside the React Component and add the state.

```
const [prevSteps, setPrevSteps] = React.useState({
    individual: false,
    bulk: true,
    firstScreening: true,
    secondScreening: false
});
```

For the `Checkbox` component you will have to add two more attributes `name` and `checked`. Here the `checked` attribute should bind with the respective state variable.

```
<Checkbox
   color="primary"
   checked={prevSteps.individual}
   inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
   onChange={setStepsSelection}
   name="individual"
/>
```

Then the method `setStepsSelection` will only update the check properties.

```
  const setStepsSelection = (event) => {
    setPrevSteps({ ...prevSteps, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
  };
```

Once you have the selection data available last step is to format it at step 3.

```
const preOptions = [
  "individual",
  "bulk",
  "firstScreening",
  "secondScreening"
];

return preOptions.filter((element) => prevSteps[element]).join(" --> ");
```

You can check the full code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-d09g0?file=/demo.js:3436-3647).

Comment: one issue i am not getting if i select bulk then why its selecting default  second screen and also if i select bulk and second screen then step 3 why its getting like this BulkFirst Screening also if i go back and change field then its not clearing data its adding

Comment: i think if i go back data is not getting clear that by its getting like this IndividualBulkFirst ScreeningSecond Screening

Comment: in this way whatever i select previous its printing in step 3 but i don't need to print that value i have two section in step 3 first is text field and second it upload file section i need to set like this way if Individual First Screening selected then text field show if Bulk First Screening then file upload show that same thing for second screen need to change

Comment: can you tell me why first screen and second screen check box selecting by default depend on previous selection

Comment: I have provided another way of doing this - that is using state. Please check https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-d09g0?file=/demo.js:3436-3647